# Linux user-space program showing its internal counters similar to /proc/meminfo

Tags: linux

In Linux I want my user-space program to give information about its internal counters, using a method similar to what is done for /proc/meminfo : the user has just to read the file to get the information.

I am thinking about using a regular file /tmp/my_counters (/tmp being in volatile memory). But this could lead to some situation where the reading of the file might result in a partial contents (if the program has not finished the writing at the same time).

Are there other good methods for this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this by implementing a simple libfuse filesystem.  When the filehandle is opened the counter is read atomically into a buffer inside the fs implementation - and then the client's read syscall reads from that memory buffer.  This avoids the sync problem you are describing as an image of the counter is taken at file open-time.

http://fuse.sourceforge.net/

Comment: FUSE is interesting. However it requires one more dependency (toward libfuse). I think I will keep the /tmp/xxx for now, and make a rename /tmp/xxx.t /tmp/xxx to have atomic reading.

Comment: I guess I don't understand, so you are going to write to the filesystem everytime the counter changes?

Comment: Yes, but as /tmp is in RAM, it won't be a heavy writing. I believe.

Comment: Sure, it depends how often the counter increments, but in your way every time the counter changes you need to make an (expensive relative to updating memory counter) write syscall, where as in my way the syscalls only occur when someone wants to read the counter.  If noone reads, than there is zero performance penalty.